# Use same adapter and ViewHolder for different activities?

Tags: android

I am developing an app that shows different pieces of information about location and weather. 
I have a MainActivity which shows information about the current place, and if you search for another one, I want to show in another activity which has the exact format as MainActivity the information. The question is, I have a RecyclerView with Adapter and ViewHolder in the MainActivity. If I use the exactly same format, can I use the same adapter and ViewHolder for the second activity?
I thought about updating the MainActivity when the user searches for a place but I want to keep the information of the MainActivity.
Here is my code for the adapter and the view holder:

```
    public class WeatherAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WeatherReportViewHolder>{
        private ArrayList<DailyWeatherReport> mDailyWeatherReport;

        public WeatherAdapter(ArrayList<DailyWeatherReport> mDailyWeatherReport) {
            this.mDailyWeatherReport = mDailyWeatherReport;

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(WeatherReportViewHolder holder, int position) {
            position+=1;

            DailyWeatherReport report=mDailyWeatherReport.get(position);

            holder.updateUI(report);
            holder.updateDate(position);


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mDailyWeatherReport.size()-1;
        }

        @Override
        public WeatherReportViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View card= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_weather,parent,false);
            return new WeatherReportViewHolder(card);
        }
    }

    public class WeatherReportViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
           .....


        public WeatherReportViewHolder(View itemView) {
           .....

        }
        public void updateUI(DailyWeatherReport report){

           .....
        }

        public void updateDate(int i){

           .....
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No problem . you can

Comment: It's possible to use the same adapter if everything like layout, view IDs etc match as you'd obviously make a new instance of it.

Comment: So there won't be any problem! Thanks!

Comment: yep, you won't get any problem , jus create new instance of it, like @gitter said.

Comment: @gitter what you mean with new instance?

Comment: Oh, I got it! Just create a new WeatherAdapter for my example.

Comment: `otherRecyclerView.setAdapter(new WeatherAdapter(weatherList));`